# run NPM script from a current path

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm

I have the following **test** script *(using ts-node package)* in my package.json file from my node project

```
"scripts": {
"build": "tsc",
"test": "ts-node"},
```

it works if I execute it in my root folder

```
npm run test helloWord.ts
```

and it works as well when I execute it inside any other subfolder *(but I need to send the entire path as parameter)*

```
npm run test src/samples/helloWord.ts
```

My question is: There is another way to avoid put the entire path and be able to execute npm run test helloWord.ts?

Comment: How about creating a batch script - assuming you are on Windows?  Set the path once in the .bat file, keep it on your Desktop and then double-click it whenever you need to execute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your scripts, you would have to specify something like

```
"scripts": {
"build": "tsc",
"test": "ts-node",
"test-hw": "ts-node src/samples/helloWord.ts"},
```

You would then be able to run the script `npm run test-hw` from anywhere within the folder/subfolders.